# How do I make a program ask the user for the number of inputs, and add the result of their inputs togther?

Tags: python

I'm currently trying to make a program that calculates your final semester grade based on the grades you received previously and how big of an impact they have on your semester grade. The problem is I'm struggling to figure out how you can make the program ask the user for the number of grades they received and then ask for the same amount of grades.

In a nutshell, the program is supposed to do the following:

1. Ask for the number of received grades
2. Ask what grade the user got and the percentage of that grade x amounts of times, where x is the number the user gave on the first question.
3. Calculate the final semester grade based on the inputs.

I hope someone can help, I've made this code so far in case it helps you to understand what I'm trying to do.

```
grade1 = int(input("What was the first grade you received? " ))
percentage1 = float(input("What's the percentage of the first grade? "))
grade_value1 = grade1 * percentage1

grade2 = int(input("\nWhat was the second grade you received? "))
percentage2 = float(input("What's the percentage of the second grade? "))
grade_value2 = grade2 * percentage2

grade3 = int(input("\nWhat was the third grade you received? " ))
percentage3 = float(input("What's the percentage of the third grade? "))
grade_value3 = grade3 * percentage3

finale_grade = grade_value1 + grade_value2 + grade_value3

if finale_grade < 2.9:
    print("\nYour finale grade is 2")
elif finale_grade < 5.4:
    print("\nYour finale grade is 4")
elif finale_grade < 8.4:
    print("\nYour finale grade is 7")
elif finale_grade < 10.9:
    print("\nYour finale grade is 10")
else:
    print("\nYour finale grade is 12")
```

Comment: Why do you make the user count the grades? Just let them input as many as there are and count them when they type an empty line or quit command. You could even update the average after each input.

Answer (score 1):

```
#I hope this works , I'm a beginner tho 

num_of_recieved_grades = int(input("number of recieved 
grades ?"))
final_grade = 0

# for loop in range of the number entered

for x in range (num_of_recieved_grades ):
    grade = int(input("what is the grade"))
    percentage = float(input("what is the percentage"))
    final_grade += grade * percentage
```

Comment: It worked, thank you so much. I tried using a for loop previously, but it didn't work so I thought it was the wrong approach.

Comment: All the best bro